# HTML Browser Based link to invoke iPhone/iPad or Android application to launch itself

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, html, appmobi

Is there any known method to provide a link on a static html page that would in turn open an app on an iPhone/iPad or android if said app exists? I know you can make call links, I know you can get the market to launch via itunes, but is there a standard format for a link for either device type?

kinda like `mailto:`, other things like launching IRC? in a manor of speaking? If this exists, how is it done? Is this something I can do in javascript? jquery or similar library? other?

I should mention the app in question is not a native app, its being created through appmobi, not sure if that makes a world of difference or not. All though it does make me realize that its web site has a method of launching apps from browser. Just not sure how its done.

Comment: A link to a file will try to launch that file with native OS predefined app for that file. I supose that if you create a link to an app launcher, it will fire upon clicking. If that app's launcher is on a known path you could create a link to it.

Comment: Is there a means of finding out such information about an app, Im sure if I was making it natively I would be able via xcode to know more information like that, unfortunately I am bound to the choice I made to use appmobi as my objective c, and java (android) are not as good as my server side and client side scripting

Comment: I don't know much about mobile device programming, but I supose that apps should have something like an execution path defined somewhere inside the device. When an app is installed this value is filled and a pointer to the launcher is created. Maybe you can scan this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - I'm, a developer at appMobi

appMobi does provide a protocol handler for every app built.  It is your company name, a period, then your app name.

So if your company name is "developer" and your app name is "test"

```
<a href='developer.test://'>Launch my app</a>
```

Comment: Awesome! THank you. When I get home I am gonna have to give this a shot.